# Index file not loading automatically for Alias in Virtual Host

Tags: apache2, ruby-on-rails

I have the following virtual host setup:

```
RailsBaseURI /

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain
    DocumentRoot /usr/share/redmine/public

    Alias /evaluation /home/user/evaluation/

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm

    <Directory /usr/share/redmine/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/user/evaluation/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `mydomain/evaluation`, I get an error. But when I go to `mydomain/evaluation/index.php`, it works. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update:**
I have confirmed that the request is routed to Redmine instead of being handled by Apache. Any ideas?

Comment: What error exactly, a 404? And what URL does the server think is being requested? What if you request `mydomain/evaluation/` (note the trailing slash)?

Comment: I get this `Page not found

The page you were trying to access doesn't exist or has been removed.

Back` which makes me think the request is being sent to Redmine, which is the Rails application running on /. `mysite/evaluation/` produces the same error.

Comment: Ok just confirmed, the request is routed to Redmine. Why doesn't Apache handle it itself?

Comment: No idea what's wrong?