# URL Alias not working in Apache with Redmine

Tags: apache2, ruby-on-rails

This is a follow-up to my original post [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71057/index-file-not-loading-automatically-for-alias-in-virtual-host?noredirect=1) because I got no answer there. The problem is that the request is being routed to Redmine despite the fact that Apache has an Alias for it. Anybody have any solutions?

Comment: I read your original question. I do not know Redmine. Sorry. But what I did notice is that you said you got an error but did not tell us what that error was. Can you post it for us? As well as any other information that may be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Questions can be updated by editing them, but please do not post another question as an update to a previous one.

Comment: Ooopppsss. I guess I did not read the comments.

Comment: @dan apologies for that but as there was no reply to that thread anymore I was not sure how to bump it. Should I continue with the old thread?

Comment: @closetnoc no worries. Redmine is a Ruby on Rails application that works via the Passenger module. Any ideas about that?

Comment: @KG Yes. questions that haven't received answers that have been accepted or voted on will periodically be added back to the "active" list of questions automatically by the system. Editing the question will also add it to the active list, however that should only be done to make a correction, clarification, or add an update.